# Zend_Form: Using HtmlTag Decorator twice?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to wrap the form element in a div AND the whole block (label, element, errors etc) in another div using the HtmlTag decorator? I'd like to use Twitter's Bootstrap with Zend_Form like so:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <label for="xlInput">X-Large Input</label>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="xlInput" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$element->setDecorators( array(
    'Errors',
    'ViewHelper',
    array( array( 'wrapperField' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'input' ) ),
    array( 'Label', array( 'placement' => 'prepend' ) ),
    array( array( 'wrapperAll' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'clearfix' ) ),
) );
```

**edit:** Label was wrong; adjusted.

Comment: Brilliant! Now, **WHERE** in ZF is this documented?

Answer (score 2):

In reply to Ezequiel Muns, here's where it is in the documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.7/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.decorators Look for the callout section "Note: Using Multiple Decorators of the Same Type."